# Capturing command output in Powershell as string instead of array of strings

Tags: powershell

I am trying to capture the output of running an external command as a string, but the result returned by Powershell is always an array of strings. It is my understanding that Powershell splits the output on newlines (Windows or Unix line endings) and stores the result in an array, but I would like these newlines to be preserved since this is for an svn pre-commit hook script to detect if a committed file has mixed line endings.

```
$output = svnlook cat -t $transId -r $repos $filename
```

At this point line endings have been stripped, and `$output` is an array of strings, one per line of output.

Redirecting to a file does not seem to work since this normalizes the line endings. How do you tell Powershell to not split a command's output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just wrap the "inner" command in parentheses, and use the `-join` operator with `` "`n" `` on the right.

```
# Preserve line breaks
$result = (ipconfig) -join "`n";

# Remove line breaks
$result = (ipconfig) -join '';
```

Answer (score 16):

Pipe the command output into the [`Out-String`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849952.aspx) cmdlet:

```
$output = svnlook cat -t $transId -r $repos $filename | Out-String
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need it as a single string, you can just cast the result to [string]

```
[string]$output = svnlook cat -t $transId -r $repos $filename
```

Comment: Note that tis concatenates the lines without putting newlines in, as opposed to the out-string solution.